# Shortcut for making text Style bold

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout

I know how to set the Text Style bold. But is there any Shortcut as like `<B>` tag in HTML that can make Some words as bold.
Ex. :
phone:9825056129

In above text i want to set the phone as bold and the remaining as the normal text. So is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setspan as showun in following link
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/text/Link.html

Comment: Hummmm, Nice. Actualy i want to set it in to the xml file but anyway thanks for the valuable reply. . .

Comment: If you find any difficulty let me know

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Write your text as HTML and then use Html.fromHtml to get it into a form that is understood by TextView

E.g.

```
TextView mtv = ...
mtv.setText(Html.fromHtml(s + " <b>" + status.getInReplyToScreenName() + "</b>"));
```